# What is the proof of divisibility by $13$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While solving the question of [$26^{th}$ digit given by **@The Lone Wolf**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048449/finding-26th-digit-of-a-number) a question arrived in my mind; the question was

Everyone knows the divisibility rule of $13$.

**Test for divisibility by $13$:** Add four times the last digit to the remaining leading truncated number. If the result is divisible by 13, then so was the first number.

**For Example :** $$50661$$ $$5066+4=5070$$ $$507+0=507$$ $$50+28=78$$

and $78$ is $6\times13$, so $50661$ is divisible by $13.$

Please help me!!!

Comment: Please include / link a proof and tell us *precisely* what you don't follow.

Comment: I removed the "logic" tag - that refers to a specific field of mathematics, not general reasoning.

Comment: A general version of divisibility rules of the type where we separate the last digit and then add/subtract a multiple of it to the integer formed by the rest of the digits is explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961065/11619). Together with a proof. I think that this is a duplicate, but I have promised not to instaclose...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree, so I started the mark-as-duplicate process the "normal" way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint** $\ 13\mid 10a\!+\!b\iff 13\mid \color{#c00}4\,(10a\!+\!b)\equiv \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{a\!+\!4b}\pmod{\!13}$

i.e. $ $ scale $\ 10a\!+\!b\,\ $ by $\, \dfrac{1}{10}\equiv \dfrac{-12}{-3}\equiv \color{#c00}4\,\pmod{\!13}\ $ to make $a$'s coef $\equiv 1.$

**Remark** $ $ This works for any modulus $\,n\,$ coprime to the radix $\,r\, $ (by $1/r$ exists mod $n$ by Bezout).

However, the *universal* divisibility test [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52815/242) is often simpler, and has the major advantage of computing true remainders, so it can be used for general arithmetic mod $n$

Comment: I am just getting my feet wet with number theory so bear with me as I've only stumbled upon this. I want to know why the if and only if statement holds true. thank you.

Comment: @The If $a,b$ are coprime then $\,a\mid bn\iff a\mid n\,$ by Euclid's Lemma (or by considering their unique prime factorizations). Or, more directly, notice that $\ 13\mid 4n\iff 13\mid n\ $ by $$\   \begin{align}\bmod 13\!:\ n\equiv 0&\overset{\times\ 4}\Longrightarrow\,4n\equiv 0\\[.2em]
4n\equiv 0&\overset{\times (\color{#c00}{-3})}\Longrightarrow\ n\equiv 0
\end{align}$$ where we scaled by the inverse of $\,4,\,$ i.e.  $\,\dfrac{1}{4}\equiv \dfrac{-12}4\equiv\color{#c00}{-3}$ $\quad$

Comment: is that supposed to be $-12n \equiv 0$?

Comment: @The No, we used $\ 1\equiv -12\pmod{\!13}\ $ to make the division exact.

Comment: I found Deepak's answer more suited to me as a newbie. thank you for linking my question here!

Comment: @The Deepak's answer uses essentially the same method, i.e. he uses the $2$nd congruence below, which arises from (my) $1$st congruence below by scaling it by $\,1/\color{#c00}4 \equiv \color{#c00}{-3}\pmod{\!13}$
$$\begin{align} \color{#c00}4\,(10a+b) &\equiv\ \  a+4b\qquad\ \pmod{\!13}\\
\iff\ \ \ \ 10a+b\ \, &\equiv (a+4b)(\color{#c00}{-3})\!\pmod{\!13}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

First, let me prove a more general statement: if $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, a polynomial with integer coefficients, is divisible by $x+3$, then $Q(x)=a_nx^{n-1}+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2x+a_1+4a_0$, when divided by $x+3$, has a remainder which is divisible by 13. Once this is established, your rule of divisibility by 13 then follows if one plugs in $x=10$.

By Remainder Theorem, if $P(x)$ is divisible by $x+3$, then 
\begin{eqnarray}
P(-3)=a_n(-3)^n+a_{n-1}(-3)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(-3)+a_0=0.
\end{eqnarray}
Let $y$ be the remainder of $Q(x)$ on division by $x+3$. Again by Remainder Theorem, 
\begin{eqnarray}
Q(-3)=a_n(-3)^{n-1}+a_{n-1}(-3)^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2(-3)+a_1+4a_0=y.
\end{eqnarray}
We can easily see that 
\begin{eqnarray}
-3y-P(-3)=-13a_0\\
3y=13a_0.
\end{eqnarray}
Since both $y$ and $a_0$ are integers, and 3 and 13 are co-prime, $y$ is divisible by 13.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to prove this specific divisibility rule for $13$? If so, it's not hard with modulo arithmetic.

To separate the units place from the rest of the number, you can express it as $10x + y$, where $y$ represents the units place.

$10x + y = 13x - 3x + 13y - 12y = 13(x+y) -3(x+4y) \equiv -3(x+4y) \pmod{13}$

Since $3$ is coprime to $13$ (no factors other than $1$ in common), if $x+4y \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$ (another way of saying $x+4y$ is divisible by $13$), then $10x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$, which proves the divisibility rule.

You can now express that rule in a simple algorithm: strip off the last digit, multiply it by $4$ and add that to the remaining number. If the new number is divisible by $13$, then so was the original number.

You can also find similar (i.e. slightly "ugly") rules for divisibility by $7$ and other odd primes using similar methods. For instance, for $7$, the rule is strip off the last digit, double it and subtract that from the remainder of the number. If the new number is divisible by $7$, so was the original. ($10x + y = 7(x+y) + 3(x-2y) \equiv 3(x-2y) \pmod 7$).